# Extract the real components from a very large expression

Tags: performance-tuning, evaluation, formatting

Suppose I have a very long expression (>500,000 characters) which contains a mixture of real and imaginary terms. e.g `x = g*m*o*p*q*s*v + a*c*f*g*m^2*o*p*q*s*v + c*g*h*m^2*o*p*q*s*v - a*c*g*h*m^2*o*p*q*s*v - B*g*m*o*p*q*s*v*w - g*m*o*p*s*v*x - (1-I*Sqrt[3])*(2*g*o*p*s*v + 2*a*c*f*g*m*o*p*s*v) + 2*c*g*h*m*o*p*s*v + (1+I*Sqrt[3])*(2*g*p*q*v + m*g*f*q*m*o*s*v)...` etc. I would like to seperate the real and imaginery terms and work with the real terms only.

I am using `ComplexExpand[Re[x],TargetFunctions->(Re)}]` but I keep getting the message 'No more memory available. Mathematica has shut down.Try quitting other applications and then retry'.

Is there a better way to discard the imaginary terms and group the real terms together without this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your expression is indeed a sum of terms as shown in your example you might want to try

```
expression = 
   g*m*o*p*q*s*v + a*c*f*g*m^2*o*p*q*s*v + c*g*h*m^2*o*p*q*s*v - 
   a*c*g*h*m^2*o*p*q*s*v - B*g*m*o*p*q*s*v*w - 
   g*m*o*p*s*v*
   x - (1 - I*Sqrt[3])*(2*g*o*p*s*v + 2*a*c*f*g*m*o*p*s*v) + 
   2*c*g*h*m*o*p*s*v + (1 + I*Sqrt[3])*(2*g*p*q*v + m*g*f*q*m*o*s*v)
```

ComplexExpand[Re[#], TargetFunctions -> (Re)] & /@ expression

> 2 g p q v - 2 g o p s v - 2 a c f g m o p s v + 2 c g h m o p s v +
>   f g m^2 o q s v + g m o p q s v + a c f g m^2 o p q s v +   c g h m^2
>   o p q s v - a c g h m^2 o p q s v - B g m o p q s v w -   g m o p s v
>   x

This works because you can use `Map` (`/@`) on any function, not only on `List`. With a sum of terms you have an expression `Plus[...]`on the outside. With `Map` you now use `ComplexExpand` on the parts instead of on the whole. This may alleviate memory problems.

Whether it works for your long expression without memory problems I didn't test.

Comment: Thanks for response. Unfortunately it still runs out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

If, as it seems in your question, the expression is a polynomial (or even a rational function)  and the variables are all real, then this should work:

```
expr = 
 g*m*o*p*q*s*v + a*c*f*g*m^2*o*p*q*s*v + c*g*h*m^2*o*p*q*s*v - 
  a*c*g*h*m^2*o*p*q*s*v - B*g*m*o*p*q*s*v*w - g*m*o*p*s*v*x -
   (1 - I*Sqrt[3])*(2*g*o*p*s*v + 2*a*c*f*g*m*o*p*s*v) + 
  2*c*g*h*m*o*p*s*v + (1 + I*Sqrt[3])*(2*g*p*q*v + m*g*f*q*m*o*s*v)

expr /. zz_Complex :> Re[zz]

(*
  2 g p q v - 2 g o p s v - 2 a c f g m o p s v + 2 c g h m o p s v + 
    f g m^2 o q s v + g m o p q s v + a c f g m^2 o p q s v + 
    c g h m^2 o p q s v - a c g h m^2 o p q s v - B g m o p q s v w - 
    g m o p s v x
*)
```

If you have algebraic or transcendental functions in your expression, then it might not work.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have evaluated the full expression and the one using `zz_complex:>Re[zz]` by substituting some numerical values for all the parameters, however, the magnitude of the real component is different in both. I think my expression contains some algebraic functions.